# how to mock react-query useQuery in jest

Tags: jestjs, react-query

I'm trying to mock out axios that is inside an async function that is being wrapped in useQuery:

```
import { useQuery, QueryKey } from 'react-query'


export const fetchWithAxios = async () => {
   ... 
   ...
   ...
   const response = await someAxiosCall()
   ...
   return data
}

export const useFetchWithQuery = () => useQuery(key, fetchWithAxios, {
    refetchInterval: false,
    refetchOnReconnect: true,
    refetchOnWindowFocus: true,
    retry: 1,
  })
```

and I want to use moxios

```
  moxios.stubRequest('/some-url', {
      status: 200,
      response: fakeInputData,
    })

    useFetchWithQuery()

    moxios.wait(function () {
      done()
    })
```

but I'm getting all sorts of issues with missing context, store, etc which I'm iterested in mocking out completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mock `useQuery`, mock Axios!

The pattern you should follow in order to test your usages of `useQuery` should  look something like this:

```js
const fetchWithAxios = (axios, ...parameters) => {
   const data = axios.someAxiosCall(parameters);
   return data;
}
export const useFetchWithQuery = (...parameters) => {
 const axios = useAxios();
 return useQuery(key, fetchWithAxios(axios, ...parameters), {
    // options
  })
}
```

Where does `useAxios` come from? You need to write a context to pass an axios instance through the application.

This will allow your tests to look something like this in the end:

```js
const { result, waitFor, waitForNextUpdate } = renderHook(() => useFetchWithQuery(..., {
   wrapper: makeWrapper(withQueryClient, withAxios(mockedAxios)),
});
await waitFor(() => expect(result.current.isFetching).toBeFalsy());
```

Comment: like I said, I _am_ mocking axios. I'm having trouble with the fact that useQuery is dependant on a store and on context, two things I do not wish to setup in my test.

Comment: @NiRR You need to use `renderHook`, and wrap it in the `QueryClientProvider` context. You can't use hooks without them.